# How to generate asgi.py for existent project?

Tags: python, django, wsgi, django-3.0, asgi

I have an existent django project in 2.2, but now i would like to start using channels, so I have to change to 3.0 and asgi instead of wsgi.

How can I generate the asgi.py that I need to run the app?

Comment: Have you read [this](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deploying.html#run-protocol-servers)? And you don't need to use Django 3.0 to use channels by the way.

Answer (score 5):

Django has a template file [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/7f19e3713598a37b0809b5434114140170d12e34/django/conf/project_template/project_name/asgi.py-tpl) that it uses to generate the `asgi.py`.

Jus copy paste this next to your `wsgi.py`:

```
import os

from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', '{{ project_name }}.settings')

application = get_asgi_application()
```

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the module `django.core.asgi` does not exist in Django 2.2, the version mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

For `Django==2.2`, I found the solution in [this link](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/2.x/deploying.html#run-protocol-servers). For the `asgi.py` file, the content would be:

```
"""
ASGI entrypoint. Configures Django and then runs the application
defined in the ASGI_APPLICATION setting.
"""

import os
import django
from channels.routing import get_default_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.settings")
django.setup()
application = get_default_application()
```