# Django Asyncronous task running syncronously with asgiref

Tags: django, asynchronous

I'm receiving notification in my Django app via API and I should return HTTP 200 before 500 milliseconds. To achieve that I should run the related task asynchronously. I'm using `asgiref` library for it, everything runs ok but I think is not actually running asynchronously.

**Main viev**

In this view I receive the notifications. I set 2 print points to check timing in the server log.

```
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(('POST',))
@renderer_classes((TemplateHTMLRenderer, JSONRenderer))
def IncomingMeliNotifications(request):
    print('--------------------------- Received ---------------------')
    notificacion = json.loads(request.body)
    call_resource = async_to_sync(CallResource(notificacion))
    print('--------------------------- Answered ---------------------')

    return Response({}, template_name='assessments.html', status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

**Secondary view**

After receiving the notification I call the secondary view `CallResource`, which I expect to run asynchronously.

```
def CallResource(notificacion):
    do things inside....
    print('--------------------------- Secondary view ---------------------')

    return 'ok'
```

**Log results**

When I check the log, I always get the prints in the following order:

```
print('--------------------------- Received ---------------------')
print('--------------------------- Secondary view ---------------------')
print('--------------------------- Answered ---------------------')
```

But I suppose that the `Secondary view`should be the last to print, as:

```
print('--------------------------- Received ---------------------')
print('--------------------------- Answered ---------------------')
print('--------------------------- Secondary view ---------------------')
```

What am I missing here?

I'm reading the documentation [github.com/django/asgiref](https://github.com/django/asgiref) and as far as I can tell this should be the paradigm I'm working on:

> If the outermost layer of your program is synchronous, then all async
> code run through AsyncToSync will run in a per-call event loop in
> arbitrary sub-threads, while all thread_sensitive code will run in the
> main thread.

Any clues welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`async_to_sync` lets a sync thread stop and wait for an async function, not run a sync function asynchronously.

## Running an asynchronous task

1. Since you didn't mention an ASGI server, it appears you are running the sync development server `python manage.py runserver`.
   If so, install and run [Daphne](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/asgi/daphne/) (from Django) instead.

```sh
pip install daphne
```

```sh
daphne myproject.asgi:application
```

<sub>If you're using Django 3.x and above, there should already be an asgi.py file in the same directory as your wsgi.py file. See [docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/asgi/](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/asgi/).</sub>

<sub>If you're using Django 2.x and below, upgrade to Django 3.x and above and create the asgi.py file. See [How to generate asgi.py for existent project?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62032184/8601760).</sub>

2. You can create an async task when running an ASGI server.

```py
# call_resource = async_to_sync(CallResource(notificacion))
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
task = loop.create_task(CallResource(notificacion))
```

3. An async function should be defined with `async def`.

```py
# def CallResource(notificacion):
async def CallResource(notificacion):
```

Comment: Thanks @aaron Just been able to grant the reward. Best!